# Extract data from the register and run a docker command using loop

Tags: docker, devops, ansible-2.x

My ansible version is 2.7

Below is the myplaybook

```
           postgresql_query:
             db: xyz
             login_host: xyz
             login_user: xyz
             login_password: xyz
             query: SELECT image_id, docker_image_url, docker_image_tag FROM xyz.inserttest;
           register: imageinfo
         - debug:
              msg: "{{ imageinfo.query_result }}"
```

When i run this playbook o/p will be like this

```
TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "docker_image_tag": "17", 
            "docker_image_url": "jdk", 
            "image_id": 1
        }, 
        {
            "docker_image_tag": "11", 
            "docker_image_url": "jdk", 
            "image_id": 2
        }, 
        {
            "docker_image_tag": "8", 
            "docker_image_url": "jdk", 
            "image_id": 3
        }, 
        {
            "docker_image_tag": "16", 
            "docker_image_url": "nodejs", 
            "image_id": 4
        }
    ]
}
```

Now i want to run a **docker pull** command for each of these images and also extract the sha value using the command **docker images --no-trunc --quiet imageurl:imagetag"** in loop ans store these sha value using ansible.

can someone please help with these?

for ex i

Answer (score 0):

Something just along:

```
community.docker.docker_image:
  name: "{{ item.docker_image_url }}/{{ name.docker_image_tag }}"
  source: pull
items: imageinfo.query_result
```